# Cannot create a LinkedList of 7M Long type variables in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to create a very large linked list as below, but it failed (ran as a unit test in maven. Already set heap size by running "set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx4096m" (i'm running in windows).

The code failed after inserting about 6M (6000000) Long items into the list. Why? Considering Long type is 8 bytes, 6M Long type variables are just 48M bytes. Even if Java object has some additional hidden fields, it shouldn't fail so early.

```
 int N = 100000000;

    try {

        LinkedList<Long> buffer = new LinkedList<Long> ();

        for(int i=0;i<N;++i) {
            buffer.add((long)i);

            if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("added " + i);

            }
       }
   catch(Exception e)
   {...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each entry in the list is a separate object, with a reference to the previous and next nodes, as well as the current value.

If we assume 8 bytes per reference, and an object overhead of 16 bytes, that means for each entry you've got:

- A entry object: 40 bytes (3 references + overhead)
- A Long object: 24 bytes (data + overhead)

So after 6000000 entries that would be about 384M... which you should still be okay with. (Depending on your JVM, I'd expect the reference size and per object overhead to be lower, too.)

I wonder whether your MAVEN_OPTS is either being set in the wrong place, or not used for JVM arguments for some reason. I've just tried running this on my Windows box (not as a unit test - just as a `main` method) and with the JVM default allocation, it fails after 6 million entries for me too. With `-Xmx1024M` it gets to 25 million entries, which suggests a smaller overhead than I've estimated above. (I'm on a 32-bit VM though.)

That certainly suggests your MAVEN_OPTS isn't doing what you want...

Comment: +1: He's on a 64-bit JVM if his maximum size is `-Xmx4096m`, making the size per long as 72+32 or 104 bytes per long. Using `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` would mean the sizes are the same as a 32-bit JVM but I believe he is using th wrong data structure.

Comment: @Peter: Where do you get 72 + 32 from? Even if there's a 24 byte overhead, that would make it 48 + 32 wouldn't it?

Comment: Hmmm, 72 is not correct. 40-48 is closer. I should have tested it.

Comment: Testing it with a 64-bit JVM its about 48 bytes.

Comment: thanks. It turns out the MAVEN_OPTS doesn't help for junit test. I modified the POM.xml for surefire and added the following lines, then it works:<forkMode>pertest</forkMode>  
<argLine>-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m</argLine>  
<testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>

Answer (score 2):

LinkedList is about the most memory inefficient way to store a series of longs.  You have the Long object which is about 3x larger than a plain long and you have a linkedList entry which is doubly linked making its about 5x larger than a plain long.

I sugegst you use a `long[]` or a wrapper like TLongArrayList which use almost 8 bytes per long for a large collection. (It will be faster too)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the memory taken up by

```
LinkedList$Entry
```